# Python 3: modified yahtzee/ 3 of a kind, 4 of a kind, 5 of a kind or nothing

Tags: python-3.5

I'm writing a modified Yahtzee game in Python 3 called '5 Dice' where the user only wins if they roll a 3, 4, or 5 of a kind. I am using a list for the dice roll but I am having trouble comparing the random list values and now it doesn't even want to work. Please help!

```
    import time
    import os
    import random

    number_of_dice = 5

    rolls = []

    def dice_roll():
        os.system("clear")
        print("Welcome to 5 Dice!")
        raw_input("Press ENTER to roll")
        for q in range(number_of_dice):
            rolls.append(random.int(1,6))
        rolls.sort()
        time.sleep(1)
        print(*rolls)

        if rolls[0] == rolls[2]:
            print("You rolled a three of a kind!")
            try_again()
        if rolls[0] == rolls[3]:
            print("You rolled a four of a kind!")
            try_again()
        if rolls[0] == rolls[4]:
            print("You rolled a five of a kind!")
            try_again()

def try_again():
    choice = input("Would you like to play again? Y/N: ")
    if choice == "Y" or choice == "y":
        dice_roll()
    if choice == "N" or choice == "n":
        quit()
    else:
        print("Please type Y or N")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can currently see two problems with your code:
1.
Firstly, your code is indented at the beginning for some reason. This results in an indentation error, which could be why your program is not even working. If you move all the code at the start backwards, it should work.
2.
When you are comparing the dice, you say: if rolls[0] == rolls[2]. This doesn't mean three are the same, because you are only comparing two of the dice! It should be more like: if rolls[0] == rolls[1] == rolls[2]. If you change this, your game should work.
I hope this helps.